# Find frequency response of built-in functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to plot the frequency response of the built-in Matlab function `diff` for comparison purposes. Is this possible?

**Later edit**

This plot should be done without using `fft` on the `diff` result.

Comment: One naive way that comes to mind is to generate test signals of varying frequencies, apply `diff` on them and compare the input/output by FFT.

Answer (score 1):

Your measured frequency response will not depend on the *frequency* of the input signal—theoretically the response is (1, π/2)—but on the *sampling frequency* of the input (since `diff` computes the finite differences). The bigger the sampling frequency compared to the input frequency, the nearer to theoretical values you'll get.

For crazy-high input frequencies/crazy-low amplitudes you'll have the frequency "response" depending on the floating point resolution (see `eps` function) too, which is another "sampling" effect of fitting real numbers in a finite amount of bits.

But to answer your question: yes, it is possible.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Did you try mikkola's suggestion? (is in the comments of your post)

Comment: No, because my question is essentially on how to avoid doing that.

Comment: You might be able to directly calculate it (to a constant factor being equal to your time step), by using the response function of the derivative operator

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist You should state that in your question. Here, let me add that to your post.